# IE form POST params missing

Tags: internet-explorer, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, post, paperclip

I have a multipart Rails form that includes a Paperclip attachment. When I post it in Firefox, Chrome, or Safari, there is no problem. When I post it in IE, my last two params are completely missing in the request (not blank). They are simple text input fields with very small values. The problem occurs regardless of whether or not there is an attachment included. I have a similar form for a different model which is not multipart, and has fewer inputs. It works fine in IE. There are never exceptions in the production log, but there are errors because I validate the presence of these missing attributes.

Does anyone have any suggestions about what may cause this issue, or know of a way to debug this in IE?

EDIT - code as requested:

## model

```
class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo
  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_uniqueness_of :name, :scope => [:foo_id]
  validates_numericality_of :first_missing_attribute, :second_missing_attribute, :message => 'must be a number'
  has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :original => ["300x300>"], :thumb => ["100x100>"] }
end
```

## html rendered

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/myapp/foos/1/bars" class="new_bar" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="new_bar" method="post">
  <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
    <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="01h99m2ZuOAApUNvFCmBSOydMd1IvE0yujLCzSP0lDk=" />
  </div>
  <div class="step">
    <div class="step-count">
      <img alt="One" src="/images/one.png?1299957833" />
    </div>
    <div class="step-field">
      <p>NAME</p>
      <input id="bar_name" name="bar[name]" size="35" type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="step">
    <div class="step-count">
      <img alt="Two" src="/images/two.png?1299957833" />
    </div>
    <div class="step-field">              
      <p>CONTENT</p>
      <select id="bar_formatted" name="bar[formatted]"><option value="false">Keep it simple</option><option value="true">Let me add html & css</option></select><br />
      <textarea cols="40" id="bar_content" name="bar[content]" rows="20" style="text-align:left;"></textarea>
      <div class="file-input">
        <p>ADD AN IMAGE</p>
        <input id="bar_image" name="bar[image]" type="file" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>          
  <div class="step">
    <div class="step-count">
      <img alt="Three" src="/images/three.png?1299957833" />
    </div>
    <div class="step-field">
      <input id="search" type="text" onkeypress="return preventEnter(this, event)"/><input id="find-location" type="button" value="Fly To" onClick="buttonClick()"><br />
      <form name="bazs" id="bazs" method="get">
          <select onChange="flyTo(this.value);" style="max-width:200px; font-size: 12px; color:#003300" name="locator">
            <option value="Baz1">Baz1</option>
            <option value="Baz2">Baz2</option>
            <option value="Baz3">Baz3</option>
          </select>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="step">
    <div class="step-count">
      <img alt="Four" src="/images/four.png?1299957833" />
    </div>
    <div class="step-field">
      <input id="set-bar" type="button" value="Generate" onClick="setBar()">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="step">
    <div class="step-count">
      <img alt="Five" src="/images/five.png?1299957833" />
    </div>
    <div class="step-field">
      <div id="loading">
        <img alt="loading" src="/images/loading.gif?1299957833" />
      </div>
      <div id="inputs">
        <div class="input">
          <p>FIRST MISSING ATTRIBUTE</p><input id="bar_first_missing_attribute" name="bar[first_missing_attribute]" onBlur="checkValue(this)" onFocus="removeImage(this)" size="30" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div class="input">
          <p>SECOND MISSING ATTRIBUTE</p><input id="bar_second_missing_attribute" name="bar[second_missing_attribute]" onBlur="checkValue(this)" onFocus="removeImage(this)" size="30" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div class="save">
          <img alt="Clear" onClick="submitForm()" src="/images/clear.png?1299957833" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>            
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: especially interested in your model code

Comment: and the HTML code of the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't nest a form inside of a form.

Thanks to http://webdevrefinery.com/forums/user/6599-theempty/.